# Embed video from url in UITableViewCell with autoplay like Twitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

as my question says, i want to embed videos in UITableViewCell like twitter. With autoplay without sound.

This is my setSelected method in VideoCell.m

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   // Configure the view for the selected state
   NSURL *urlVideoFile = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlVideo];
   NSAssert(urlVideoFile, @"Expected not nil video url");

   _playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
   _playerViewController.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:urlVideoFile];
   _playerViewController.view.frame = self.viewVideo.bounds;
   _playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

   [self.viewVideo addSubview:_playerViewController.view];
   self.viewVideo.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
   _playerViewController.player.play;
}
```

But obviously is not the best way to do because is very slowly to load videos and for consecuences, the scroll of the table is being interrupted continously!

I would like to know wich is the best approach for make this! Thanks!

Sorry for my english!

EDIT:

I solved de load issue, that issue that blocks the table scrolling, with dispatch_assync method.

I delete the code inside setSelected and put this in the cellForRow in main view controller

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrayVideos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    cell.videoItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        cell.videoPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:cell.videoItem];
        cell.avLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:cell.videoPlayer];
        cell.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        cell.avLayer.frame = CGRectMake(cell.tapaVideo.frame.origin.x,
                                        cell.tapaVideo.frame.origin.y,
                                        cell.tapaVideo.frame.size.width,
                                        cell.tapaVideo.frame.size.height);

        [cell.contentView.layer addSublayer:cell.avLayer];
        //[cell.videoPlayer play];
        //[cell.contentView addSubview:cell.videoActivity];
    });
});
```

But i still having the "overlapping issue".

[image]

Comment: i edited the question